# Cannot draw Terrform cycle with colors using `terraform graph` with plan output file

Tags: terraform

I want to generate a resource graph using `terraform graph` that includes my cycle coloured. For this purpose, I first generate a plan, as `terraform graph` without `-plan` option shows no cycle (why?):

```
terraform plan -var-file ../../config/bff/dev.config.tfvars -out tfplan.out
```

It results in cycle errors as below, but the plan file is still created:

[image]

Now, when I execute the `terraform graph`, I get the same cycle errors, with no dot output:

```
terraform graph -draw-cycles -plan=tfplan.out -type=apply
```

How can I generate the a graph for my cycle, if the cycle prevents me from generating output?

Comment: I think it should be something like `terraform graph -draw-cycles -type=apply | dot -Tpdf > graph-plan.pdf`, which will generate a PDF file with cycles, but for that you also need the Graphviz installed.

Comment: Don't you need the plan? :)

Comment: As far as I can remember, I don't think so.

Comment: Please share your terraform code ... I personally never had any success with the -draw-cycles command when there is a cycle I get an error and no graph outputs

Comment: I just tested this with a very simple cycle and I get the same ... I reported the bug with the team: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/34639 ... leave your comment there and if you can your TF code as an alternative to reproduce the issue